# SQL Trigger for updating values from a query by id

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have three tables:

- employee with id(employee id), numOfTickets
- tickets with date, asset(id) and some more fields
- control with id(employee id), asset(id)

when a new ticket is created it automatically inserts a row into tickets and control.
Now I want to create a Trigger or something similar to automatically update the number of open tickets for each employee.

A Query for selecting the employee id and the number of open tickets looks like:

```
SELECT employee, COUNT(*) FROM control GROUP BY employee
```

This works. But I tried to make a Trigger AFTER INSERT into control like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `TEST_b` 
AFTER INSERT ON `control` 
FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE `employee` SET `numOfTickets` = ( 
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM control WHERE employee=( 
        SELECT employee FROM control GROUP BY employee));
```

But it does not work. I don't know if this is even possible with a Trigger.
So the goal is to set the number of open tickets for each employee by id returned from the first Query.

I would need some kind of Iteration.

Comment: Its usually a bad idea keeping totals like this, specially when all you have to do is run the query that works to find the number if and when you actually want to know it

Comment: Its specially wastful updating all employees when only one has changed

Comment: Did you try this update before parking in trigger?

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause is invalid. The last subquery returns multiple employees, you can't compare that with `=`. I'm not even sure why you're using that subquery.

Comment: You should just use `WHERE employee = NEW.employee`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes I agree, but the "Project" is about having this kind of Redundancy in the employee table + working with Triggers...

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes it worked with LIMIT 1; but then obviously only one employee id/number of tickets was selected and everybody got the same "numOfTickets"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only set `numOfTickets` for the same employee that's being updated, and get the count for that employee.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `TEST_b` 
AFTER INSERT ON `control` 
FOR EACH ROW 
    UPDATE `employee` SET `numOfTickets` = ( 
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM control WHERE employee_id=NEW.employee_id
    )
    WHERE employee_id = NEW.employee_id;
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I needed to add to your Solution a JOIN to get it working correctly.

Comment: What did you need to join with?